# How to grow yourself when your task is not specific?

Tags: career-development, performance

I have been working on different tasks chosen by myself as a specific task is not allocated. I am free to choose tasks. Due to lack of a specific job task and needing to work on different tasks I find that I am not growing much or I don't know if I am growing very fast.

So, how do I measure if I am growing? How do I grow myself when I need to handle different tasks and have no specific task?

Comment: "specific task is not allocated" - does that mean your boss doesn't care at all what you do all day long? Wow - nice work if you can get it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure your employer hired you for serving a specific purpose, unless you are hired for the man-friday position. Why don't you go to the hiring manager and start a discussion with him/her, saying something like *"I enjoy having the freedom of picking and choosing my tasks in my such-and-such years/months of employment with you, but I want to help our organization be more effective, by undertaking assignments which are crucial to the success of the team. What do you think I can start working on?"*

Every professional organization has goals. Goals get divided unto smaller goals and the division goes down to the simplest of tasks to accomplish the goal. It looks like you are stuck at the bottom of that totem pole. You may want to broaden your point of view and instead of focusing of individual tasks, you may try to see the bigger picture and how those tasks you perform, come together for a greater purpose. It will give you the insight about each task in the project plan as well as planning/managing the whole project. This can easily catapult your career into a project management position with the technical expertise about the job you are performing. Once you have few of such assignments and successful completions under your belt, you can write your own ticket, without worrying your professional development not being as fast as you hoped it would be. Mainly because you will not have time to think about such minor details once you get into the big-picture world and there is a lot to learn that way.

Comment: very well said.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd talk to your boss/employer. Get an idea of what their expectations are for the position and make sure you are meeting them. Ask them what their expectations are for your future development.

Next, assuming they don't care about your future development or you feel you are already on track, start thinking about where you want to be in several years. What skills do you want to develop? Is the kind of work you're doing now at the company you work at now what you want to be doing in the future? Create your own development plan. Outline the skills and possibly any education you need to get you there. If you think your boss would be open to it, go over the plan with them. Maybe there are tasks within your company you can work on that will get you there, or possibly your employer is willing to pay for classes/books. If you don't think they would open to it, or your ambitions are far beyond theirs, don't worry. Just work on your own personal development plan as you can while getting your job done.

Comment: the development plan making strategy is good one !

Answer (score 0):

I would make an appointment with your employer and try to find out what (s)he would like you to do. I understand that you have a lot of freedom in your work, but since they have to pay you he most likely does care what you do with your time. Make a list of tasks that you would like to do and that are good for the company and propose them to your employer. Let him choose which ones he finds most interesting. After this, set clear goals for each of your tasks and work towards them.

Comment: I do that but I find I am doing more R&D and unable to measure my goal.

Comment: @kinkajou it takes some work but you can make things like that into clear, measurable tasks.  For example "Explore options for scenario X and prepare brief report on a recommendation."

Comment: @dan1111 How do I decide if scenario is okay? I don't have any end customers.